# E/Volley: [1871] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://52.91.77.158:8087/api/v1/auth/signin

Tags: android

I tried to `Signin` if the credentials success it has shown success message and response.once if its credentials wrong it doesn't show response (error code, and message).its shown

> E/Volley: [1871] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://52.91.77.158:8087/api/v1/auth/signin.please give me answer .my code is below.

Comment: `give me answer` first ask a question. As for what you wrote - all that is expected behavior. HTTP code 401 (Unauthorized) means exactly that your authorization failed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I have one doubt if credentials are matches its give response that case no Authorised is not mentioned and we need to add authorised in wrong credential cases?